# (erb):48:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have no idea about the issue.
I can start my application and want to update **database.yml** after that I cannot run the application on my machine (**macOS Catalina 10.15.7**) then I discard changes in **database.yml** but I still got the following error:

```
=> Booting Puma
=> Rails 6.1.0 application starting in development
=> Run `bin/rails server --help` for more startup options
Exiting
(erb):48:in `<main>': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb.rb:905:in `eval'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/erb.rb:905:in `result'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/secrets.rb:28:in `block in parse'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/secrets.rb:25:in `each'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/secrets.rb:25:in `each_with_object'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/secrets.rb:25:in `parse'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:406:in `secrets'
from /Users/superman/Desktop/finsonaly/config/initializers/devise.rb:242:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/devise-4.7.3/lib/devise.rb:307:in `setup'
from /Users/superman/Desktop/finsonaly/config/initializers/devise.rb:3:in `<main>'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:59:in `load'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `block in load'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:326:in `load'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:681:in `block in load_config_initializer'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:205:in `instrument'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:680:in `load_config_initializer'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:634:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `each'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/engine.rb:633:in `block in <class:Engine>'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:32:in `run'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:61:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:350:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:422:in `block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:421:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `each'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `tsort_each_child'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:415:in `call'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:415:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:349:in `block in each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `call'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:226:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/3.0.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:60:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/application.rb:384:in `initialize!'
from /Users/superman/Desktop/finsonaly/config/environment.rb:8:in `<main>'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/zeitwerk-2.4.2/lib/zeitwerk/kernel.rb:34:in `require'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:53:in `require_relative'
from config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `eval'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:116:in `new_from_string'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:105:in `load_file'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/builder.rb:66:in `parse_file'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:349:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:249:in `app'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/rack-2.2.3/lib/rack/server.rb:422:in `wrapped_app'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:77:in `log_to_stdout'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:37:in `start'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:144:in `block in perform'
from <internal:kernel>:90:in `tap'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/commands/server/server_command.rb:135:in `perform'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor/invocation.rb:127:in `invoke_command'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/thor-1.0.1/lib/thor.rb:392:in `dispatch'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/command/base.rb:69:in `perform'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/command.rb:50:in `invoke'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/railties-6.1.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<main>'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `require'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:23:in `block in require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/loaded_features_index.rb:92:in `register'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:22:in `require_with_bootsnap_lfi'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/bootsnap-1.5.1/lib/bootsnap/load_path_cache/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:31:in `require'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `block in require'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:299:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/superman/.rbenv/versions/3.0.0/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/activesupport-6.1.0/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:332:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Here is my code:
**database.yml**

```
# PostgreSQL. Versions 9.3 and up are supported.
#
# Install the pg driver:
#   gem install pg
# On macOS with Homebrew:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/usr/local/bin/pg_config
# On macOS with MacPorts:
#   gem install pg -- --with-pg-config=/opt/local/lib/postgresql84/bin/pg_config
# On Windows:
#   gem install pg
#       Choose the win32 build.
#       Install PostgreSQL and put its /bin directory on your path.
#
# Configure Using Gemfile
# gem 'pg'
#
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  # For details on connection pooling, see Rails configuration guide
  # https://guides.rubyonrails.org/configuring.html#database-pooling
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: abcdb

  
test:
  <<: *default
  database: abcdb_test


production:
  <<: *default
  database: abcdb_production
  username: test
  password: <%= ENV['ABCDB_DATABASE_PASSWORD'] %>
```

Can anyone advise me on how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure your issue isn't in "finsonaly/config/initializers/devise.rb"?

Comment: Perhaps it is not recognizing `ENV` as a keyword, so it is throwing the error on the very last line of your code snippet? I am not sure why that would be happening though . . .

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks, I've checked the error is from this 
`config.omniauth :facebook,      Rails.application.secrets.facebook_api_id.to_s, 
                                  Rails.application.secrets.facebook_api_secret.to_s, 
                                  scope: 'email', 
                                  info_fields: 'email,name',
                                  image_size: 'large'`

<br>this syntax `Rails.application.secrets.facebook_api_id.to_s` error when I update rails to v6.1.0

Comment: @Romeo do you have an issue in your secrets file `"config/secrets"` where `[]` is being called on a `nil` object during the parsing.

Comment: @engineersmnky Yes, it seems "config/secrets.yml" is conflicting with `secrets = YAML.load(ERB.new(preprocess(path)).result) || {}` in "rails/secrets.rb". I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: @engineersmnky the error is from this 
      `def parse(paths, env:)
        paths.each_with_object(Hash.new) do |path, all_secrets|
          require "erb"

          secrets = YAML.load(ERB.new(preprocess(path)).result) || {}
          all_secrets.merge!(secrets["shared"].deep_symbolize_keys) if secrets["shared"]
          all_secrets.merge!(secrets[env].deep_symbolize_keys) if secrets[env]
        end
      end`

Comment: @Romeo the error is actually from this part `ERB.new(preprocess(path)).result` which `result` is trying to eval some erb in your secrets file and that erb is calling `[]` on a `nil` object. If you can reasonably post that file without exposing any actual secrets it is likely the error will become more obvious

Comment: @engineersmnky these are syntaxes from `"config/secrets"` 1. `facebook_api_id: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:facebook][:FACEBOOK_PUBLIC_KEY] %>` 2. `facebook_api_secret: <%= Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:facebook][:FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY] %>`

Comment: @Romeo there is your issue. In your credentials.yml.enc file you are missing the `development` entry or the `facebook` entry and thus it is returning `nil` and then trying to call `[]` on that `nil` object.

Comment: @engineersmnky I have this
`development:
  stripe:
    STRIPE_PUBLIC_KEY: xxx
    STRIPE_SECRET_KEY: xxx
    STRIPE_PRODUCTE_ID: xxx

  facebook:
    FACEBOOK_PUBLIC_KEY: 6xxx
    FACEBOOK_SECRET_KEY: axxx`

Comment: @engineersmnky in `"/initializers/devise.rb"` when I change from `config.omniauth :facebook,      Rails.application.secrets.facebook_api_id.to_s, Rails.application.secrets.facebook_api_secret.to_s,  scope: 'email',  info_fields: 'email,name', image_size: 'large'` to `config.omniauth :facebook, "6xxx",                                    "axxx",  scope: 'email',  info_fields: 'email,name', image_size: 'large'` there is no error but I don't want to do this way. It's 1 a.m. at my local time I'll try and update you again tomorrow

Comment: @Romeo totally understand but you will need to update your question with the contents of this discussion as the information provided is paramount to the answer and the formatting (specifically of YAML files) is extremely important. Try changing the devise to `Rails.application.credentials[Rails.env.to_sym][:facebook][:FACEBOOK_PUBLIC_KEY].to_s` and see if that works. It may be that you are trying to use "secrets" and "credentials" at the same time when "credentials" was intended to replace secrets